# Replace single quote with backslash single quote

Tags: ruby, string

I have a very large string that needs to escape all the single quotes in it, so I can feed it to JavaScript without upsetting it.
I have no control over the external string, so I can't change the source data.

Example:

```
Cote d'Ivoir  -> Cote d\'Ivoir
```

(the actual string is very long and contains many single quotes)

I'm trying to this by using `gsub` on the string, but can't get this to work:

```
a = "Cote d'Ivoir"
a.gsub("'", "\\\'")
```

but this gives me:

```
=> "Cote dIvoirIvoir"
```

I also tried:

```
a.gsub("'", 92.chr + 39.chr)
```

but got the same result; I know it's something to do with regular expressions, but I never get those.

Comment: You may want to consider also escaping double quotes, as someone can currently break your program by doing entering `My Nefarious" Country` as their country. It's what Rails does with thier `escape_javascript` helper http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The %q delimiters come in handy here:

```
# %q(a string) is equivalent to a single-quoted string
puts "Cote d'Ivoir".gsub("'", %q(\\\')) #=> Cote d\'Ivoir
```

Comment: Actually your example returns "Cote d\\'Ivoir" not "Cote d\'Ivoir" which is the desired result.

Comment: @Dave: `p ("Cote d'Ivoir".gsub("'", %q(\\\'))).size` returns 13. (IRB uses \\ to make an escape-\ visible).

Comment: In order to use this without the %q delimiter, your replacement would be `.gsub("'", "\\\\'")` . Five backslashes and an apostrophe also return the same result. I like @steenslag's answer better anyway, much easier to read

Answer (score 22):

The problem is that `\'` in a `gsub` replacement means "part of the string after the match".

You're probably best to use either the block syntax:

```
a = "Cote d'Ivoir"
a.gsub(/'/) {|s| "\\'"}
# => "Cote d\\'Ivoir"
```

or the Hash syntax:

```
a.gsub(/'/, {"'" => "\\'"})
```

There's also the hacky workaround:

```
a.gsub(/'/, '\#').gsub(/#/, "'")
```

Comment: Al those examples give "Cote d\\'Ivoir" not "Cote d\'Ivoir"

Comment: @DaveSag - Remember that, in a `"` string, the \ will need to be escaped. The string contains `\'`, which is represented as `"\\'"`.

Comment: The easiest way to demonstrate what the REPL does with the "\\" is to puts the string

`str = "Cote d'Ivoire"
#=> "Cote d'Ivoire"`
`str = "Cote d\'Ivoire"
#=> "Cote d'Ivoire"`
`str = "Cote d\\'Ivoire"
#=> "Cote d\\'Ivoire"`
`puts str
Cote d\'Ivoire
#=> nil`

Answer (score 0):

```ruby
# prepare a text file containing [  abcd\'efg  ]
require "pathname"
backslashed_text = Pathname("/path/to/the/text/file.txt").readlines.first.strip
# puts backslashed_text => abcd\'efg

unslashed_text = "abcd'efg"
unslashed_text.gsub("'", Regexp.escape(%q|\'|)) == backslashed_text # true
# puts unslashed_text.gsub("'", Regexp.escape(%q|\'|)) => abcd\'efg
```